# qemu vnc server for remote address

Tags: desktop, vnc, qemu

qemu -vnc 0.0.0.0:1 -monitor stdio -hda ubunt*

I am running this command but it isn't opening a port.  I have checked it with netstat.  My goal is to log into the VNC server somewhere else besides locally.

Answer (score 4):

Try `qemu -vnc :1`. 0.0.0.0 should work, but according to `man qemu` omitting it should allow connections from any host.